# Are Masters 1000 tournaments mandatory for top ranked players?

Tags: rules, tennis, atp

I have read somewhere that top ranked players must play every [Masters 1000 tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_World_Tour_Masters_1000), meaning that they are mandatory for top players.

My question is: Suppose a top ranked player does not play one or two of the Masters 1000 series. Are there any penalties for him?

Comment: I have rolled back the most recent edit. ATP Masters 1000 is a series of tournaments, so it is plural, not singular.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any player that is in the Top 30 in the ATP Rankings from the previous year is considered a Commitment Player for the current year.

From the [2013 ATP Official Rulebook](http://www.atpworldtour.com/Corporate/Rulebook.aspx), I. ATP Circuit Regulations, 1.07 C:

> **Commitment Player**
> A 2013 ATP commitment player is any player
> positioned in the Top 30 in the ATP 2012  Rankings (singles) as of
> November 5, 2012.

The commitment for a commitment player is described in section D.  Essentially, the Barclays ATP World Tour Finals is required, if accepted; 8 of the 9 ATP World Tour Masters 1000 tournaments are required (all except Monte Carlo), and 4 of the ATP World Tour 500 tournaments are required.

1.07 D:

> **Commitment**
> The commitment for the commitment player is, the singles
> event of all ATP World Tour  Masters 1000 tournaments for which he is
> accepted, the Barclays ATP World Tour  Finals (if qualified as a
> direct acceptance or designated as the alternate) and four (4)  ATP
> World Tour 500 tournaments, one (1) of which must be held following
> the US  Open. For commitment and ranking purposes, the Monte Carlo
> Masters 1000 will be  included in the minimum requirements for the 500
> category. 2013 Davis Cup points  may be counted as one (1) of the best
> of six (6) in the Emirates ATP Rankings, how-ever, it shall not count
> towards the commitment requirement of a commitment player.  See page
> 184 “Ranking Penalty.”

A player can get the number of ATP World Tour Masters 1000 commitment tournaments reduced by meeting certain milestones, based on longevity in the league.

1.08:

> **1.08 Reduction of ATP World Tour Masters 1000 Commitment**
> **A.** A player’s number of ATP World Tour Masters 1000 commitment tournaments shall  be
> reduced by one (1) tournament for reaching each of the following
> milestones:
> **1)** 600 matches (as of 1 January of the commitment year);
> **2)** 12 years of service;
> **3)** 31 years of age (as of 1 January of the
> commitment year).
> If all three (3) conditions are met then the player
> has a complete exemption from the ATP World Tour Masters 1000 player
> commitment.
>
> **B.** A player who is eligible for a reduction of his ATP World Tour
> Masters 1000 commitment tournaments must be in good standing with the
> ATP in order to receive a reduction of required ATP World Tour
> Masters 1000 commitment tournaments.

If a player skips the Barclays ATP World Tour Finals without a valid excuse, they are no longer considered in good standing.

1.09 A:

> **1.09 Unsatisfied Player Commitment Penalties**
> **A. Failure To Participate in the Barclays ATP World Tour Finals**
> 1)If a player qualified for the
> Barclays ATP World Tour Finals as a direct acceptance or designated
> as the alternate, fails or refuses to participate in this event,
> except  for bona fide injury or other reason which constitutes good
> cause, the player shall  not be in good standing.

This section of the rule book does not specify a penalty for skipping other commitment tournaments.  The Rankings section of the rulebook reveals the penalty.  If the other commitment tournaments are skipped, they are counted against the player for ranking purposes.

IX. Emirates ATP Rankings, 9.03 Emirates ATP Rankings:

> **A. Commitment Players.**
> The year-end Emirates ATP Rankings is based on
> calculating, for each player, his total points from the four (4) Grand
> Slams, the eight (8)  mandatory ATP World Tour Masters 1000
> tournaments and the Barclays ATP World  Tour Finals of the ranking
> period, and his best six (6) results from all ATP World Tour  500, ATP
> World Tour 250, ATP Challenger Tour and Futures tournaments. For every
> Grand Slam or mandatory ATP World Tour Masters 1000 tournament for
> which a  player is not in the main draw, and was not (and, in the case
> of a Grand Slam, would  not have been, had he and all other players
> entered) a main draw direct acceptance  on the original acceptance
> list, and never became a main draw direct acceptance,  the number of
> his results from all other eligible tournaments in the ranking period,
> that  count for his ranking, is increased by one (1). In weeks where
> there are not four (4)  Grand Slams and eight (8) ATP World Tour
> Masters 1000 tournaments in the ranking  period, the number of a
> player’s best results from all eligible tournaments in the ranking
> period will be adjusted accordingly. Once a player is accepted in the
> main draw  of one of these twelve (12) tournaments, as a direct
> acceptance, a qualifier, a special  exempt or a lucky loser, or having
> accepted a wild card, his result in this tournament  shall count for
> his ranking, whether or not he participates.