# Why are 7 non-compulsory tournaments included in Marin Cilic's ATP ranking?

Tags: tennis, ranking

I understand that only 18 tournaments (19 if qualified for ATP Finals) are considered for ATP rankings of which 4 grand slams and 8 masters (excluding Monte Carlo) are compulsory. If a player fulfills the commitment of 4 ATP 500 (counting Monte Carlo if he plays), his best 6 results from other tournaments are counted.

But currently (16th March 2018), I see 7 tournaments (apart from compulsory tournaments) are counted in Marin Cilic's Rankings. It includes Monte Carlo, 3 ATP 500 and 3 other tournaments. Is it not violating the rule?

His ATP Rankings Breakdown is [here](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/players/marin-cilic/c977/rankings-breakdown). And here is [Internet Archive snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20180316105038/http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/players/marin-cilic/c977/rankings-breakdown) from March 2018.

Comment: Under some conditions, the commitment can be reduced, see here: [Are Masters 1000 tournaments mandatory for top ranked players?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3372) I'd guess that is is possible that Cilic already had 600 matches at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but this could be a case of them using the Monte Carlo Open in place of the Canadian Open, which he pulled out of due to an injury sustained at Wimbledon.